# CloudFormation solution in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any similar solution like CloudFormation template on Google Cloud? 
I mean like if the creation drops an error then rollback every transaction, I can define the cluster in a template file and so on...

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/map-aws-google-cloud-platform

Answer (score 27):

[Google Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) (which recently came out of beta) allows you to define and manage the infrastructure in Google Cloud - i.e. define repeatable deployments via YAML configurations.

See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration) for more details about supported resources and syntax.

Comment: and does it have automatic rollbacks?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of documentation on it, but it looks like Resource Views are what you want.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/resource-views

Answer (score -4):

The name and link have been changed to [instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates?hl=en_US&_ga=1.63522287.1103276982.1430119600)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Read the rule [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Instance templates are something different. They're close to the equivalent of EC2 AutoScaling launch configurations. Deployment Manager is Google's equivalent of CloudFormation, and there's always third-party options such as Terraform.